# How to find Atar if Ainethach is dead?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There's a dragon attack when I first meet `Karthwasten`, and `Ainethach` is killed.

After several hours of waiting I found that `Atar` and his guys has left.

So how can I find that guy now?

They are not in the `Sanuarach Mine`.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find Atar's new location anywhere, but you could try

```
player.moveto <RefID>
```

In this case, Atar's RefID is 000622E7. This will move you to wherever Atar is.

Alternatively, you could bring Atar to you with:

```
Prid <RefID>
```

followed by

```
moveto player
```

Where the RefID is once again 000622E7.

Also, for the future, try [this mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/23906/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try `player.moveto` later. If I found where he is, I'll load game and walk by foot, lol. Because I'm trying to play a normal game as possible.

Comment: That sounds good. Let me know where he ended up! I'm curious as well. I'd check myself, but I've already done that quest awhile ago.

Comment: ok sure, wait for my report, but i'll be available only after 12 hours later xD